# Deriving Mapped Distinct Values into an ObservableList off another ObservableList?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have an interesting problem, and I am relatively new to JavaFX and I need to create a somewhat niche `ObservableList` implementation.

Essentially, I need an `ObservableList` that maintains a list of mapped derived values off another `ObservableList`. I need to create an `ObservableDistinctList<P,V>` that accepts another `ObservableList<P>` and a `Function<P,V>` lambda as its constructor arguments. The `ObservableDistinctList<P,V>` maintains a list of distinct values off the applied `Function<P,V>` for each element in `ObservableList<P>`.

For example, say I have `ObservableList<Flight> flights` with the following instances.

```
Flt #   Carrier Orig    Dest    Dep Date
174     WN      ABQ     DAL     5/6/2015
4673    WN      DAL     HOU     5/6/2015
485     DL      DAL     PHX     5/7/2015
6758    UA      JFK     HOU     5/7/2015
```

If I created a new ObservableDistinctList off the carrier values of each Flight object, this is how I would do it on the client side.

```
ObservableDistinctList<Flight,String> distinctCarriers = new 
    ObservableDistinctList(flights, f -> f.getCarrier());
```

These would be the only values in that `distinctCarriers` list.

```
WN
DL
UA
```

If a flight got added to `flights`, it would first check if a new distinct value is actually present before adding it. So a new `WN` flight would not cause an addition to the `distinctCarriers` list, but an `AA` flight will.  Conversely, if a flight gets removed from `flights`, it needs to check if other instances would persist the value before removing it. Removing a WN flight from `flights` would not cause a removal of `WN` from the `distinctCarriers` list, but removing the `DL` flight will cause its removal.

Here is my implementation. Did I implement the `ListChangeListener` correctly? I get really uncomfortable with List mutability so I wanted to post this before I consider using it in my project. Also, do I need to worry about threadsafety using an `ArrayList` to back this?

```
public final class ObservableDistinctList<P,V> extends ObservableListBase<V> {

    private final ObservableList<P> parentList;
    private final Function<P,V> valueExtractor;
    private final List<V> values;

    public ObservableDistinctList(ObservableList<P> parentList, Function<P,V> valueExtractor) {
        this.parentList = parentList;
        this.valueExtractor = valueExtractor;
        this.values = parentList.stream().map(p -> valueExtractor.apply(p)).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        this.parentList.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends P> c) -> { 
            while (c.next()) { 
                if (c.wasRemoved()) { 
                    final Stream<V> candidatesForRemoval = c.getRemoved().stream().map(p -> valueExtractor.apply(p));
                    final List<V> persistingValues = parentList.stream().map(p -> valueExtractor.apply(p)).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

                    final Stream<V> valuesToRemove = candidatesForRemoval.filter(v -> ! persistingValues.contains(v));

                    valuesToRemove.forEach(v -> values.remove(v));
                }

                if (c.wasAdded()) { 
                    final Stream<V> candidatesForAdd = c.getAddedSubList().stream().map(p -> valueExtractor.apply(p));
                    final List<V> existingValues = parentList.stream().map(p -> valueExtractor.apply(p)).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

                    final Stream<V> valuesToAdd = candidatesForAdd.filter(v -> ! values.contains(v));

                    valuesToAdd.forEach(v -> values.add(v));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public V get(int index) {
        return values.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return values.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your ObservableDistinctList need to be a list or can it be an mapped event stream as provided by [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX)? (Just trying to see if an alternate approach might actually suit you better than what you are attempting to do now).  Also, is order important?  If not, would using an [ObservableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableSet.html) help?

Comment: Order might actually be important, but I need to bind this to TableView and ListView so I don't think I can use a set. Although I am all for third party libraries, I'm trying using this for a component in the ControlsFX project and I don't want to go through the hurdles of bringing in a dependency.

Comment: I'll need to check out ReactFX though. Reading the description sounds intriguing.

Comment: Just to be clear, this question is a request for a review and check of the implementation you have included in the question?

Comment: Yes, if that is appropriate for SO.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is for .. code reviews :-) Again, why re-invent the wheel? The octagon here is that you are missing to produce the notification. TransformList looks like a suitable starting point: it'll hook the listener to source for you. You'll still have to implement sourceChanged, update internal state inside beginChange/endChange block and post appropriate changes to the changeBuilder.

Comment: Yeah after doing some research, no doubt I need to use TransformList. I even found a MappedList that does what I want it to do, minus the distinct part. https://gist.github.com/TomasMikula/8883719

Comment: after reading your requirement (... cough ...), I'll back out of using TransformationList: it assumes a 1:(1,0) relationship between elements in source/transform such that transform.getSourceIndex() returns a single unambigous index in the source.

Comment: Yeah that did occur to me. The getSourceIndex is pretty useless for what I am trying to implement. I am submitting this code to the ControlsFX project to support a control I am building. There are plenty of experts there, including Jonathon Giles, who can verify the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simple example (plus driver - hint: that's what you should have provided in the question :-) custom ObservableList that keeps distinct values of a property of the elements in a source list. It keeps itself sync'ed to the source on adding/removing items. The sync is implemented by:

- listening to list changes of source
- when receiving a removed: if the removed had been the last with the distinct property, remove that property from oneself and notify its own listener about the removal. Otherwise, there's nothing to do.
- when receiving an added: if the added is the first with the distinct property, add the property to oneself (at the end) and notify its own listeners about the addition. Otherwise, there's nothing to do.

The notification is handled by messaging the utility methods nextRemove/nextAdd as appropriate.

```
/**
 * Example of how to implement a custom ObservableList.
 * 
 * Here: an immutable and unmodifiable (in itself) list containing distinct
 * values of properties of elements in a backing list, the values are extracted
 * via a function 
 */
public class DistinctMapperDemo extends Application {

    public static class DistinctMappingList<V, E> extends ObservableListBase<E> {

        private List<E> mapped;
        private Function<V, E> mapper;

        public DistinctMappingList(ObservableList<V> source, Function<V, E> mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
            mapped = applyMapper(source); 
            ListChangeListener l = c -> sourceChanged(c);
            source.addListener(l);
        }

        private void sourceChanged(Change<? extends V> c) {
            beginChange();
            List<E> backing = applyMapper(c.getList());
            while(c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    wasAdded(c, backing);
                } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    wasRemoved(c, backing);
                } else {
                    // throw just for the example
                    throw new IllegalStateException("unexpected change " + c);
                }
            }
            endChange();
        }

        private void wasRemoved(Change<? extends V> c, List<E> backing) {
            List<E> removedCategories = applyMapper(c.getRemoved());
            for (E e : removedCategories) {
                if (!backing.contains(e)) {
                    int index = indexOf(e);
                    mapped.remove(index);
                    nextRemove(index, e);
                }
            }
        }

        private void wasAdded(Change<? extends V> c, List<E> backing) {
            List<E> addedCategories = applyMapper(c.getAddedSubList());
            for (E e : addedCategories) {
                if (!contains(e)) {
                    int last = size();
                    mapped.add(e);
                    nextAdd(last, last +1);
                }
            }
        }

        private List<E> applyMapper(List<? extends V> list) {
            List<E> backing = list.stream().map(p -> mapper.apply(p)).distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return backing;
        }

        @Override
        public E get(int index) {
            return mapped.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return mapped.size();
        }

    }

    int categoryCount;
    private Parent getContent() {
        ObservableList<DemoData> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new DemoData("first", "some"),
                new DemoData("second", "some"),
                new DemoData("first", "other"),
                new DemoData("dup", "other"),
                new DemoData("dodo", "next"),
                new DemoData("getting", "last")

                );
        TableView<DemoData> table = new TableView<>(data);
        TableColumn<DemoData, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        TableColumn<DemoData, String> cat = new TableColumn<>("Category");
        cat.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("category"));
        table.getColumns().addAll(name, cat);

        Function<DemoData, String> mapper = c -> c.categoryProperty().get();
        ObservableList<String> mapped = new DistinctMappingList<>(data, mapper);
        ListView<String> cats = new ListView<>(mapped);

        Button remove = new Button("RemoveSelected DemoData");
        remove.setOnAction(e -> {
            int selected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); 
            if (selected <0) return;
            data.remove(selected);
        });

        Button createNewCategory = new Button("Create DemoData with new Category");
        createNewCategory.setOnAction(e -> {
            String newCategory = data.size() == 0 ? "some" + categoryCount : 
                data.get(0).categoryProperty().get() + categoryCount;
            data.add(new DemoData("name" + categoryCount, newCategory));
            categoryCount++;
        });
        VBox buttons = new VBox(remove, createNewCategory);
        HBox box = new HBox(table, cats, buttons);
        return box;
    }

    public static class DemoData {
        StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
        StringProperty category = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "category");

        public DemoData(String name, String category) {
            this.name.set(name);
            this.category.set(category);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty categoryProperty() {
            return category;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(getContent()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are an artist, thank you! I think I see how it all connects now. `ListChangeListener` is subscribed to the `source`, which fires off the `sourcedChanged()` handler. In between the `beginChange()` and `endChange()` you handle all additions and removals which gets passed to some change builder behind the scenes. the `wasAdded()` and `wasRemoved()` are pretty interesting. They are so imperative but it seems to handle all those index argument nuances. This will help me a lot not just for my immediate problem, but understand the `ObservableBaseList`. Thank you!

Comment: You might be interested in a little more streamlined and complete version of @kleopatra ´s code : https://gist.github.com/flasheater/908ca858ffc21337856a

Comment: Note that the call to "distinct()" in "applyMapper()" is commented out in this example because it violates the single responsibility principle IMO. I would have implemented a separate DistinctList if I was in need of that functionality. Or maybe use the "filtered()" of ObservableList, if it can be used for stateful filtering.