# Implement a TransformList that holds distinct values?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to create an implementation of TransformList that maintains a list of distinct values off a source list. However, I'm a little puzzled on how the implementation should add the distinct values to my hashmap and distinct list that are contained internally. I think my `ListChangeListener.change` should work though. But how do I intercept any new or removed distinct values and add/remove them to the distinct map and list?

```
public class DistinctList<E> extends TransformationList<E,E> {

    private final ObservableList<E> distinctList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<E,E> distinctValues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ObservableList<E> source;

    public DistinctList(ObservableList<E> source) {
        super(source);
        this.source = source;
        source.stream().filter(s -> attemptAdd(s)).forEach(s -> distinctList.add(s));
    }
    private boolean attemptAdd(E e) {
        final boolean result = distinctValues.putIfAbsent(e,e) == null;
        if (result) {
            distinctList.add(e);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private boolean attemptRemove(E e) {
        final boolean result = distinctValues.remove(e, e);
        if (result) {
            distinctList.remove(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void sourceChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends E> c) {
        fireChange(new ListChangeListener.Change<E>(this) {

            @Override
            public boolean wasAdded() {
                if (c.getAddedSubList().stream().filter(v -> distinctValues.contains(v) == false).findAny().isPresent()) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean wasRemoved() {
                if (c.getRemoved().stream().filter(v -> !source.contains(v)).findAny().isPresent()) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean wasPermutated() {
                return false;
            }


            @Override
            protected int[] getPermutation() {
                throw new AssertionError("getPermutation() not implemented");
            }

            @Override
            public List<E> getRemoved() {
                return c.getRemoved().stream().filter(v -> !source.contains(v)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }

            @Override
            public int getFrom() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getTo() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean next() {
                return c.next();
            }

            @Override
            public void reset() {
                c.reset();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceIndex(int index) {
        return IntStream.range(0,source.size()).filter(i -> source.get(i).equals(this.get(i))).findAny().orElse(-1);
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return distinctList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return distinctList.size();
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

I kept working with this and I think I figured out where to interact source changes with the distinct value map and list. But when my source list removes a value (and other values with same hashcode/equals still exists), it wrongly removes the value from the distinct values. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class DistinctList<E> extends TransformationList<E,E> {

    private final ObservableList<E> distinctList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<E,E> distinctValues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ObservableList<E> source;


    public DistinctList(ObservableList<E> source) {
        super(source);
        this.source = source;
        source.stream().forEach(s -> attemptAdd(s));
    }
    private boolean attemptAdd(E e) {
        final boolean result = distinctValues.putIfAbsent(e,e) == null;
        if (result) {
            distinctList.add(e);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private boolean attemptRemove(E e) {
        final boolean result = distinctValues.remove(e, e);
        if (result) {
            distinctList.remove(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void sourceChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends E> c) {
       ListChangeListener.Change<E> change = new ListChangeListener.Change<E>(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean wasAdded() {
                if (c.getAddedSubList().stream().filter(v -> source.contains(v)).findAny().isPresent()) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean wasRemoved() {
                if (c.getRemoved().stream().filter(v -> source.contains(v) == false).findAny().isPresent()) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean wasPermutated() {
                return false;
            }


            @Override
            protected int[] getPermutation() {
                throw new AssertionError("getPermutation() not implemented");
            }

            @Override
            public List<E> getRemoved() {
                return c.getRemoved().stream().filter(v -> source.contains(v) == false)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }

            @Override
            public int getFrom() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getTo() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean next() {
                return c.next();
            }

            @Override
            public void reset() {
                c.reset();
            }
        };

        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                c.getAddedSubList().stream().filter(v -> !distinctValues.containsKey(v)).peek(a -> System.out.println("ADDING FROM MAP " + a)).forEach(a -> attemptAdd(a));
            }
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                c.getRemoved().stream().filter(v -> distinctValues.containsKey(v)).peek(a -> System.out.println("REMOVING FROM MAP " + a)).forEach(a -> attemptRemove(a));
            }
        }

        fireChange(change);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceIndex(int index) {
        return IntStream.range(0,source.size()).filter(i -> source.get(i).equals(this.get(i))).findAny().orElse(-1);
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return distinctList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return distinctList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: not exactly a duplicate but closely related to an earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29656772/203657

Comment: In spirit yes it is a duplicate, although I posted this attempting a pretty different vector of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. Let me know if I'm missing anything.

```
public class DistinctList<E> extends TransformationList<E,E> {

    private final ObservableList<E> distinctList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<E,E> distinctValues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ObservableList<E> source;


    public DistinctList(ObservableList<E> source) {
        super(source);
        this.source = source;
        source.stream().forEach(s -> attemptAdd(s));
    }
    private boolean attemptAdd(E e) {
        final boolean result = distinctValues.putIfAbsent(e,e) == null;
        if (result) {
            distinctList.add(e);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private boolean attemptRemove(E e) {
        final boolean result = distinctValues.remove(e, e);
        if (result) {
            distinctList.remove(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void sourceChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends E> c) {

      while (c.next()) {
          ListChangeListener.Change<E> change = new ListChangeListener.Change<E>(this) {
              @Override
              public boolean wasAdded() {
                  if (c.getAddedSubList().stream().filter(v -> distinctValues.contains(v) == false).findAny().isPresent()) {
                      return true;
                  } else {
                      return false;
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public List<E> getAddedSubList() {
                return c.getAddedSubList().stream().filter(v -> distinctValues.contains(v) == false).collect(Collectors.toList());
              }

              @Override
              public boolean wasRemoved() {
                  if (c.getRemoved().stream().filter(v -> source.contains(v) == false).findAny().isPresent()) {
                      return true;
                  } else {
                      return false;
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public boolean wasPermutated() {
                  return false;
              }


              @Override
              protected int[] getPermutation() {
                  throw new AssertionError("getPermutation() not implemented");
              }

              @Override
              public List<E> getRemoved() {
                  return c.getRemoved().stream().filter(v -> source.contains(v) == false)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
              }

              @Override
              public int getFrom() {
                  return 0;
              }

              @Override
              public int getTo() {
                  return 0;
              }

              @Override
              public boolean next() {
                  return c.next();
              }

              @Override
              public void reset() {
                  c.reset();
              }
          };

          if (change.wasAdded()) {
              change.getAddedSubList().stream().filter(v -> !distinctValues.containsKey(v)).peek(a -> System.out.println("ADDING FROM MAP " + a)).forEach(a -> attemptAdd(a));
          }
          if (change.wasRemoved()) {
              change.getRemoved().stream().filter(v -> distinctValues.containsKey(v)).peek(a -> System.out.println("REMOVING FROM MAP " + a)).forEach(a -> attemptRemove(a));
          }
          fireChange(change);
      }

    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceIndex(int index) {
        return IntStream.range(0,source.size()).filter(i -> source.get(i).equals(this.get(i))).findAny().orElse(-1);
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return distinctList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return distinctList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't look into the details, but: don't manage the change yourself - you'll most probably do it wrong, it's  not trivial, the collections team took years to get it right! -  instead use the nextXX (XX = Replace/removed/added etc) methods.

Comment: Okay ill take a look. I think it is worth learning how to transform lists though because complex business problems often morph data. But I certainly want to use any helper classes available instead of going low level.